# Same mathematical expression returns different result

Tags: c#, .net, math, equations

I am baffled by this one.

So I have a console application doing a lot of calculations (trust me, thousands of them ). In one method, I have some parameters that need calculating, in different situations. For one of them, the mathematical expression is basically the same, only one difference in a term. Here is the code snippet along with all the lines between the 2 formulas in question, the Nq1 and Nq2 ones ( first formula of the code and last one to be more easy ):

```
//drained conditions
        Nq1 = Math.Round((Math.Pow(Math.E, Math.PI * Math.Tan(studiu.Fi * Constants.ConversionToDeg)) * Math.Pow((Math.Tan(45 + studiu.Fi / 2.00) * Constants.ConversionToDeg), 2)), 2);

        //Combination 2

        studiu.Fi = FiAfectat;


        //drained conditions
        Nq2 = Math.Round((Math.Pow(Math.E, Math.PI * Math.Tan(studiu.Fi * Constants.ConversionToDeg)) * Math.Pow((Math.Tan(45 + studiu.Fi / 2.00) * Constants.ConversionToDeg), 2)), 2);
```

The first formula returns 18.04 but the second one returns 0.01. How is this possible ? Only the studiu.Fi term differs, but not by that much ( 32 in the first case and 27 in the second ).

How can Nq1 be 18 and Nq2 be 0.01 ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: `For one of them, the mathematical expression is basically the same, only one difference in a term.` OK, shorten your code to a few lines ask a specific question. Don't expect us to read this wall of code....

Comment: Run it line by line in the debugger and verify each intermediate result.

Comment: There's really no chance I'm going to read through that giant list of operations. Minimize your code to the shortest possible example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This is a good example of why it's important to break up long scripts into encapsulated methods. You seem to be using #regions, which is a poor alternative. If this wasn't one massive method, it would be much easier to identify the point of failure.

Comment: You know that you can eliminate identical pieces of code using functions, right?

Comment: You are speaking of 2 formulas, but I see zillions of formulas. Why don't you show us exactly those two formulas.

Comment: Edited guys, sorry ! The only relevant information remains there

Comment: There are some variables/constants not clearly demonstrated to search for a solution. And multiply PI  for the tangent of another multiplication may be overflowing/underflowing the calculation. Anyway, the best approach is DEBUG and WATCH all variables between these two calls.

Comment: Define a function for the calculation and invoke it to the slightly different `fi` angle values. If difference is not as expected then examine partial results. Little inaccuracies of angle might cause huge differences in range.

Answer (score 0):

Tan(x) is a periodic function that will change drastically for a small change in x.  Since the two formulas only differ by a term inside the Tan function, this is likely your problem.

Also, it is likely that you should be using radians instead of degrees.  If this is the case you should use a command that converts real numbers to radians instead of one that converts to degrees.